# Mercurial command to probe remote file size

Tags: mercurial

<s>Is there a way, preferrably builtin mercurial command, to get some information about remote files/directory *before* pulling to local fs?</s>

EDIT: The initial wording may have been somewhat unclear; I'd like to find out how big the repository is, how much storage space will it occupy/need.  Is it possible to get that info from the manifest file?  Essentially, Is there a way, preferrably builtin mercurial command, to get some information about remote files/directory **before cloning** to local fs?

Answer (score 0):

```
hg incoming -h
hg incoming [-p] [-n] [-M] [-f] [-r REV]... [--bundle FILENAME] [SOURCE]

aliases: in

show new changesets found in source

    Show new changesets found in the specified path/URL or the default pull
    location. These are the changesets that would have been pulled if a pull
    at the time you issued this command.

    For remote repository, using --bundle avoids downloading the changesets
    twice if the incoming is followed by a pull.

    See pull for valid source format details.

    Returns 0 if there are incoming changes, 1 otherwise.

options:

 -f --force             run even if remote repository is unrelated
 -n --newest-first      show newest record first
    --bundle FILE       file to store the bundles into
 -r --rev REV [+]       a remote changeset intended to be added
 -B --bookmarks         compare bookmarks
 -b --branch BRANCH [+] a specific branch you would like to pull
 -p --patch             show patch
 -g --git               use git extended diff format
 -l --limit NUM         limit number of changes displayed
 -M --no-merges         do not show merges
    --stat              output diffstat-style summary of changes
 -G --graph             show the revision DAG
    --style STYLE       display using template map file
    --template TEMPLATE display with template
 -e --ssh CMD           specify ssh command to use
    --remotecmd CMD     specify hg command to run on the remote side
    --insecure          do not verify server certificate (ignoring web.cacerts
                        config)
 -S --subrepos          recurse into subrepositories

[+] marked option can be specified multiple times

use "hg -v help incoming" to show more info
```

Comment: I meant **before cloning** to local fs; my apologies if that wasn't clear.  I'll edit my question to reflect this clearer.